# A connected set which is not path-wise connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $S$ be the union of $A$ and $B$ which are defined as

$$A=\left\{(x,y): 0<x\leqslant1,y=\sin\left(\frac 1x \right)\right\}\,$$
and $$B=\left\{(x,y): -1\le x \le 0, y=0 \right\}\,$$

Then I am using this definition of connected set which say that $S$ is connected if it cannot be expressed as the union of two sets such that $\,\overline A\bigcap B= \varnothing\,$ or $\,A\bigcap\overline B=\varnothing\,$.

**My Attempt:** Here clearly $\overline B=B$ which doesn't intersect with $A$. So $S$ has been expressed as a union of two sets such that $A\bigcap\overline B=\varnothing$. So it is disconnected.
But the complex analysis text (by Kasana) where I found this set says it is connected but not pathwise connected.

I can see why it is not path-connected because I found from wikipedia that the set $A$ is actually a part of topological sine curve and there is no path which connect the set $B$ to set $A$ lying entirely in S, but **I am unable to understand it's connectedness.**

**My background:** I haven't study any topology book yet, also I am learning mostly by myself so an answer with less advanced terms used in topology is much appreciated however I know basic set topology such as open set, closed set etc.

*I also tried searching here and found many questions on topological sine curve but they were using different definitions of connected, and I don't find them duplicate so apologies if I overlook something and it's a duplicate.*

Comment: Your definition of $B$ is certainly incorrect. I guess you meant $B=\{0\}\times[-1,0]$, because $A$ is a subset of $\mathrm R^2$ while $B$ is a subset of $\mathrm R$.

Comment: My bad! I edited the definition of B what I meant.

Comment: No I didn't mean the set B which @PhilippeMalot has described. According to him, his set lies on the y axis while my set B lies on the x axis

Comment: In this case $\bar{A}\cap B=\{(0,0)\}\neq\emptyset$

Comment: I have checked it's the set B I have described which is along the x axis.

Comment: Yes! I finally understood thank you everyone for their time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your definition of connectedness is not correct. It should be

> $S$ is connected if it cannot be expressed as the union of two *nonempty* sets $A,B$ such that $\overline A\cap B= \varnothing$ *and* $A\cap\overline B=\varnothing$.

In your example, $A\cap\overline B=A\cap B=\varnothing$ but $\overline A\cap B=\{(0,0)\}\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: Could you please tell me what's $\overline A$? I guess it's the A along with the y axis from -1 to 1.

Comment: I read that definition in the same book may it has typo. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Yes, $\overline A=A\cup(\{0\}\times[-1,1]).$